# ecoinvent 3.10 and brightway25 unlinked exchanges - macOS ARM

Tags: brightway

I am in the process of setting up my project for ecoinvent 3.10, but am running into the issue of not being able to import the database.

I have looked over the previous solution, which was to use ecoinvent_interface for version 0.8.12 of bw2io, however this version is not available for macOS ARM version of brightway_nosolver(current version is 0.9dev26). Therefore, the working solution provided by Chris Mutel does not work for this version.

When I try running the following, nothing changes, no install of the biosphere or anything else:

```
import bw2data as bd
import bw2io as bi
bd.projects.set_current("ecoinvent-3.10-cutoff")
bi.import_ecoinvent_release("3.10", "cutoff")
```

Is there any way to get an up-to-date version of the biosphere for ecoinvent 3.10?